# AlarmManager with RTC_WAKEUP doesnt wake device

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

In my project, I have a service that connects to an HTTP to see if it's online.
Everything works great, It does connect.

The problem is when my device goes to sleep.

I use the AlarmManager to trigger the check events, using RTC_WAKEUP, so that the process is run even when the screen is off...

The problem is that this is not really happening.
I created a Logging Method to see what happens behind the curtains of my app.

I log every step, writing the time it happened to see when and how things are happening.

When i set my device to sleep, and come back after a few minutes, I can see that the Alarm is triggering ONLY when I wake the device up, and not while it's sleeping.

Here is the code in which I create the alarm:

```
public static void AddAlarm(Context pContext, Server pServer)
{
    // Create pending with intent and server object with a helper that creates  my pending intent.
    PendingIntent pending = IntentGenerator.GetPendingIntentForAlarm(pContext,pServer.ServerId);

    // Get alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)pContext.getSystemService("alarm");

    // Get current time to start now.
    long startNow = new Date().getTime()-10;

    // Set repeating alarm with current time to start, and interval.
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,startNow, pServer.GetIntervalInMilliseconds(), pending);
}
```

And in case you are wondering how i create the pending intent:

```
public static Intent GetIntentForService(Context pContext, int pServerId)
{
    // Comienzo la alarma.
    Intent retVal = new Intent(pContext, ServerStatusCheckService.class);
    retVal.putExtra("SERVER_ID", pServerId);

    return retVal; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem was my own device. 
It's a Zenithink C93 tablet.
I tested the same code on a Motorola Defy and it worked perfectly.